# How i can save an object with more elegant way

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object:

```
var parementro = {
  myparam:{
    param:"\n ..",
    param1:"\n ..",
    param2: "\n ..",
    param3: "\n ..",
    param4: "\n \t ..",
    param5: "\n \t ..",
    param7: "\n \t .."
  },
  endparams:{
    param: "stop"   
  }
};
```

Inside the variables param,param1... there are strings and I want to write a text with this param,param1,....
 The object

```
 paramentro.myparam
```

has more params than seven. How do I save these strings without writing continuously param8,param9 etc. This object is static, it does not change dynamically and this is the reason I created the object like this.

Comment: Use an array (`myparams: [ "\n ..", "\n ..", "\n \t ..", ... ]`) instead of an object

Comment: You can use `Object.keys(paramentro.myparam)` and get all of them

Answer (score 1):

As another comment suggests you could use an Array since your keys are just incrementing each time. Then you can use various methods to populate  or manipulate the array and it's contents. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Instance_methods

But, if you do want to use an Object, you could use an array to assign keys & values to your object in a variety of ways. (this below uses [ES6](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/write-less-do-more-with-javascript-es6-5fd4a8e50ee2/) and could be modified to populate an array, too)

```
const anObject = {};

Array.from(new Array(5)).map((each, index) => anObject[`param${index}`] = "my string");
```

https://jsbin.com/baqaxocosa/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

x - (amount of params -1)

```
for(let i=0; i<=x; i+=1){
parementro.myparam = { ...parementro.myparam, [(i>0) ? `param${i}`: 'param']:'\n'}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an object

```js
var parementro = {
  myparam:{
    param:"\n ..",
    param1:"\n ..",
    param2: "\n ..",
    param3: "\n ..",
    param4: "\n \t ..",
    param5: "\n \t ..",
    param7: "\n \t .."
  },
  endparams:{
    param: "stop"   
  }
};

const obj = {...parementro.myparam}
console.log(obj)
```

if you want to use array

```js
var parementro = {
  myparam:{
    param:"\n ..",
    param1:"\n ..",
    param2: "\n ..",
    param3: "\n ..",
    param4: "\n \t ..",
    param5: "\n \t ..",
    param7: "\n \t .."
  },
  endparams:{
    param: "stop"   
  }
};

const obj1 = {...parementro.myparam}
const obj = Object.values(obj1)
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use
[Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) for this purposes:

```
let parementro = {
  myparam:{
    param:"\n ..",
    param1:"\n ..",
    param2: "\n ..",
    param3: "\n ..",
    param4: "\n \t ..",
    param5: "\n \t ..",
    param7: "\n \t .."
  },
  endparams:{
    param: "stop"   
  }
};

Object.values(parementro.myparam).join(',')
```